# Tree isomorphism problem

Tags: graph-theory

Given two Prufer sequences $P_1$ and $P_2$ that correspond to trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ of order $n$  what is the most efficient method to determine whether $T_1$ is isomorphic to $T_2$ as an *unlabelled* tree?

Having read about the difficulty of detecting isomorphic graphs via graph invariants (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11631/complete-graph-invariants) I suspect this is a hard problem.

Comment: Actually determining if two given trees are isomorphic is easy. Google "tree isomorphism." Or are you asking if it can be done by only looking at the Prufer sequences?

Comment: Hi - yes I'm asking if it can be done using the Prufer sequences only.  Sorry for having made that unclear.

Comment: You can reconstruct the labeled trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ corresponding to $P_1$ and $P_2$, remove the labels from the two trees and run a tree isomorphism algorithm on them.  It should work since $P_1$ and $P_2$ correspond to a unique labeled tree.  This takes polynomial time, I think in O(n).  But I don't see any obvious way to deduce isomorphism without reconstructing the trees, as there are $n!$ ways to relabel the nodes of $T_1$ and get a different sequence.